# Get focused MenuItem in submenu WPF

Tags: wpf, menu, keyboard, focus

I'm writing an application with menu containing submenus. Also I have a StatusBar where I want to display information about focused MenuItem when user navigates in menu with keyboard.
I tried to handle GotFocus event from each MenuItem and change StatusBar's content to sender's Tag, but it works only with MenuItem 1, not with 1.1 and 2.2.

XAML:

```
<Menu Height="23" x:Name="mainMenu">
    <MenuItem Header="Header1" Tag="Info1" GotFocus="MenuItem_GotFocus_1">
        <MenuItem Header="Header1.1" Tag="Info1.1" GotFocus="MenuItem_GotFocus_1"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Header1.2"  Tag="Info1.1" GotFocus="MenuItem_GotFocus_1"/>
        ...
    </MenuItem>
    ...
</Menu>
```

C#:

```
private void MenuItem_GotFocus_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    statusBarItem.Content = (sender as FrameworkElement).Tag;
}
```

How can I display info about submenu's focused items? Maybe are there other ways to do it?

Thanks, Aleksandr.

Comment: did any of the below help ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it applies to what you need exactly but I think it's what you need...

It's always best to bind to view-model - and then you can expose that 'status' at some other place by simply binding to it...

In case of `IsFocused` (If you're talking about the standard WPF menu items) there is a slight problem binding to it, as it's a read-only so binding fails with something like
http://meleak.wordpress.com/2011/08/28/onewaytosource-binding-for-readonly-dependency-property/
(that's also a good example of this solution, similar just for ActiveWidth/Height)

```
<TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <Setter Property="pb:PushBindingManager.StylePushBindings">
            <Setter.Value>
    <pb:PushBindingCollection>
    <pb:PushBinding TargetProperty="IsFocused" Path="IsFocused"/>
    </pb:PushBindingCollection>
            </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
```

You can download the project/lib to support that from the link in the article above (`PushBindingManager`)
Put something like `xmlns:pb="clr-namespace:PushBindingExtension;assembly=some-assembly"` (I have it copied, integrated so I don't have the exact source/naming here).

And you should be set to go. Just make `IsFocused` in your view-model, bind the menu to it - and then  put up that whatever item `is focused` at the status. There is some 'leg work' required here to get this going but pretty minimal.

Hope this helps

NOTE: use the other link for download (i.e. http://dl.dropbox.com/u/39657172/Blog/PushBindingInStyleDemo.zip)
(that one contains the `StylePushBindings` which you need, for styles.