# Execute method after value from UIElement changes

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, uielement

Is it possible to subscribe to a Property of a specific UIElement in WPF?

I want to animate an `UIElement` as soon as the Heightvalue changes and add the new height to a list, but I don't see how I can subscribe to the HeightProperty?

### Samplecode:

Something like this:

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="BibVisualization.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Border Background="Red" Width="30" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="myBorder">
        <TextBlock Text="Really really long text with wrapping, but the wrapping changes based on border's width"
               Width="{Binding ElementName=myBorder, Path=Width}"
               TextWrapping="Wrap" />
    </Border>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Height="10" 
        Content="Make border bigger" Click="OnButtonClick" />
</Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
private void OnButtonClick(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    myBorder.Width += 10;
    //Bind to textblock's actualheight and execute OnHeightChange?
}

private int accumulatedChange;

private void OnHeightChange(Object sender, SomeEventArgs? e)
{
    accumulatedChange -= e.OldValue (if possible);
    accumulatedChange += e.NewValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use the [SizeChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.sizechanged.aspx)-Event of the FrameworkElement class to do what you want. All `UIElement`s such as `Button` or `Textblock` derive from that class and therefore provide the event.

The [SizeChangedEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.sizechangedeventargs.aspx) passed to registered method contains information if height or width has changed and provide the new values.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `DependencyPropertyDescriptor` to add a `ValueChangedHandler` for the property:

```
DependencyPropertyDescriptor descriptor=DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(UIElement.HeightProperty,typeof(UIElement));
descriptor.AddValueChanged(myUIElementToWatch, new EventHandler(OnHeightOfUiElementChanged));
```

Comment: Sounded promising, but only triggers once if I do this after initializing the window, thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood properly you'd want to 'bind' to `ActualHeight` ?

Take a look at this link (http://meleak.wordpress.com/2011/08/28/onewaytosource-binding-for-readonly-dependency-property/) - it describes how it can be done using attached properties basically.

Also take a look at this answer of mine from the other day, which basically describes very similar problem.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15367642/417747
(use link there to download the support code - you can bind to via `Style` or as described in the article - it's all similar thing)

What you'd need is to bind to `ActiveHeight` using the method described in the article, that changes your view-model's `MyHeight` property - handle it's `set` to get when the active height changes. Let me know if any questions.

Hope it helps.