# ListCollectionView.CurrentPosition setter

Tags: wpf, view, setter, listcollectionview

ListCollectionView has a property get the current position (CurrentPosition):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.currentposition.aspx

But this property is read-only.

*Gets the ordinal position of the CurrentItem within the (optionally sorted and filtered) view.*

So how can one *set* the current position? I hope this doesn't involve behaviors...

I need to scroll to the top of a ListView or DataGrid and it seems to me it ought to be possible to easily set a property such as that one to achieve it, without going into the guts of a view.

Thanks in advance.

**Update:**

This is my own workaround at the moment - but it's kind of disguisting - when one wants to use MVVM (using F#):

```
let linesControl = context.Window.FindName("ObjectListView") :?> ListView
let scrollBorder = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(linesControl, 0) :?> Border
let scrollViewer = scrollBorder.Child :?> ScrollViewer
scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(0.0)
```

Comment: Both DataGrid and ListView have a method called `ScrollIntoView`. You have to pass the element you want to scroll to. `grid.ScrollIntoView(grid.Items[0])` could work in your case I guess?

Answer (score 2):

What I use is basically an `attached property` to work around the read-only, non-bindable properties (even most of the time you don't need to write, binding fails)..

This article solves similar issue with `ActualWidth` / `ActualHeight`...

http://meleak.wordpress.com/2011/08/28/onewaytosource-binding-for-readonly-dependency-property/

...and you can download the code / example there (or http://dl.dropbox.com/u/39657172/Blog/PushBindingInStyleDemo.zip).

What you use to bind is something like...

```
<pb:PushBindingManager.PushBindings>
    <pb:PushBinding TargetProperty="CurrentPosition" Path="YourPositionProperty"/>
</pb:PushBindingManager.PushBindings>
```

I didn't really try it on your example - but by the look of it - that should work the same way if there is `CurrentPosition` already.

---

Also, take a look at this earlier post for more details if needed (how to approach this for within Style etc.)...

[Get focused MenuItem in submenu WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15367161/get-focused-menuitem-in-submenu-wpf/15367642#15367642)

(disclaimer: not my article - I'm just a thankful user:)

Answer (score 1):

You can use

1) `MoveCurrentToPosition(int position)`
see : [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.listcollectionview.movecurrenttoposition.aspx)

2) `MoveCurrentTo(Object item)`
see: [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.movecurrentto.aspx)

3) `MoveCurrentToFirst()`

4) `MoveCurrentToLast()`

...

Comment: Thanks. I understood this as "move the currently selected item to the specified position", not "move view to specified position".

Comment: Tested MoveCurrentToFirst() - doesn't work here.:/ My view is virtualized - could that be a problem? I also tried to select the item first and then call MoveCurrentToFirst().